# Is there any ORM for finding latest output for component and environment

Tags: python, django

Unable to get the value correctly while i am trying annotate in Django ORM query. Please can anybody help with the correct ORM?

I am creating a deployment matrix Dashboard using django.
Here this is a dashboard for deployment detail for deployment happens in some environment through jenkins the input to the models will be given manually but we need a output in html that

`env name`  - componens(as per environmnt)
            details of the deployment according to the env and compoment

below i have showed you what output i need for my project

```
view.py
dtls = deploy_dtl.objects.values('env','comp','deploy_version').
annotate(max_date=Max('updated_dt')).order_by('env','comp')
```

This the table data under which i am querying
here 1 env can have multiple comp and i component can have multiple deployment but we want to get the latest 'updated_dt' regarding the group of components.

```
+----+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | env_id | comp_id | deploy_version | deploy_status | deploy_reqster_nme | updated_dt                 | updated_by   | remarks      |
+----+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|  2 |      1 |       1 | 1.00024        | Deployed      | Arun sahoo         | 2019-09-03 12:50:41.934499 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
|  1 |      1 |       1 | 1.00023        | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-03 10:56:52.472392 | Amit samanta | Amit samanta |
| 10 |      1 |       2 | 1.014          | Deployed      | Arun sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:10:58.475304 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
|  4 |      1 |       2 | 1.0025         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:23:37.824828 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
| 28 |      1 |       3 | 1.00024        | Deployed      | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 13:11:55.052746 | AS           | Done         |
| 18 |      1 |       3 | 1.398          | Deployed      | Arun s             | 2019-09-05 09:21:15.264997 | AS           | NIL          |
| 17 |      1 |       3 | 1.365          | Deployed      | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 09:20:43.150736 | AS           | NIL          |
| 16 |      1 |       3 | 1.325          | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:20:11.162827 | AS           | NIL          |
|  5 |      1 |       3 | 1.0235         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:24:04.431097 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
| 20 |      1 |       4 | 1.4258         | Deployed      | As                 | 2019-09-05 09:21:59.789220 | AS           | NIL          |
| 19 |      1 |       4 | 1.423          | Deployed      | Arun s             | 2019-09-05 09:21:39.496929 | As           | NIL          |
|  6 |      1 |       4 | 1.2589         | Deployed      | Arun sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:24:31.870321 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
|  9 |      2 |       1 | 2.3574         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:25:54.337903 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
|  7 |      2 |       1 | 2.055          | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:24:54.710921 | Amit Samanta | Nil          |
|  3 |      2 |       2 | 2.24           | deloyed       | Arun sahoo         | 2019-09-03 13:41:27.629124 | AS           | NIL          |
| 23 |      2 |       3 | 2.3698         | Deployed      | Arun s             | 2019-09-05 09:23:09.163000 | AS           | NIL          |
| 22 |      2 |       3 | 2.3147         | Deployed      | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 09:22:43.973396 | AS           | NIL          |
| 21 |      2 |       3 | 2.3569         | Deployed      | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 09:22:23.637389 | AS           | NIL          |
| 15 |      2 |       3 | 2.258          | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:14:15.969283 | Amit samanta | NIL          |
| 11 |      2 |       3 | 4.0147         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:11:41.344102 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
|  8 |      2 |       3 | 2.369          | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-04 15:25:32.554082 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
| 27 |      2 |       4 | 5.254          | Not Deployed  | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 13:09:18.422311 | AS           | Amit Samanta |
| 26 |      2 |       4 | 2.4587         | Deployed      | Arun S             | 2019-09-05 13:02:34.951200 | AS           | NIL          |
| 25 |      2 |       4 | 2.4587         | Deployed      | ArunS              | 2019-09-05 09:23:51.665433 | AS           | NIL          |
| 24 |      2 |       4 | 2.4569         | Deployed      | Arun s             | 2019-09-05 09:23:29.644198 | AS           | NIL          |
| 13 |      3 |       1 | 2.036          | Deployed      | Arun sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:12:50.527247 | Amit samanta | NIL          |
| 12 |      3 |       2 | 3.0123         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:12:15.371955 | Amit Samanta | NIL          |
| 14 |      3 |       3 | 5.0123         | Deployed      | Arun Sahoo         | 2019-09-05 09:13:32.753824 | Amit samanta | NIL          |
+----+--------+---------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

output i am getting

```
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
| env_id | comp_id | deploy_version | max_date                   |
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |       1 | 1.00023        | 2019-09-03 12:50:41.934499 |
|      1 |       2 | 1.0025         | 2019-09-05 09:10:58.475304 |
|      1 |       3 | 1.0235         | 2019-09-05 13:11:55.052746 |
|      1 |       4 | 1.2589         | 2019-09-05 09:21:59.789220 |
|      2 |       1 | 2.055          | 2019-09-04 15:25:54.337903 |
|      2 |       2 | 2.24           | 2019-09-03 13:41:27.629124 |
|      2 |       3 | 2.369          | 2019-09-05 09:23:09.163000 |
|      2 |       4 | 2.4569         | 2019-09-05 13:09:18.422311 |
|      3 |       1 | 2.036          | 2019-09-05 09:12:50.527247 |
|      3 |       2 | 3.0123         | 2019-09-05 09:12:15.371955 |
|      3 |       3 | 5.0123         | 2019-09-05 09:13:32.753824 |
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

expected output

```
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
| env_id | comp_id | deploy_version | max_date                   |
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
|      1 |       1 | 1.00024        | 2019-09-03 12:50:41.934499 |
|      1 |       2 | 1.014          | 2019-09-05 09:10:58.475304 |
|      1 |       3 | 1.00024        | 2019-09-05 13:11:55.052746 |
|      1 |       4 | 1.4258         | 2019-09-05 09:21:59.789220 |
|      2 |       1 | 2.3574         | 2019-09-04 15:25:54.337903 |
|      2 |       2 | 2.24           | 2019-09-03 13:41:27.629124 |
|      2 |       3 | 2.3698         | 2019-09-05 09:23:09.163000 |
|      2 |       4 | 5.254          | 2019-09-05 13:09:18.422311 |
|      3 |       1 | 2.036          | 2019-09-05 09:12:50.527247 |
|      3 |       2 | 3.0123         | 2019-09-05 09:12:15.371955 |
|      3 |       3 | 5.0123         | 2019-09-05 09:13:32.753824 |
+--------+---------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

Here i have tried multiple things but unable to find any solution.
Please help me if there are any more ways to do that the version is not showing properly i do not know what more we can do for the above output

Answer (score 0):

The model for the above project is

````
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class env_master (models.Model):
        env_code=models.CharField(max_length=8)
        env_name=models.CharField(max_length=16)
        env_active_status=models.CharField(max_length=8)
        env_pgm_release_ref=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        env_grp=models.CharField(max_length=8)
        created_dt=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.env_code


class comp_master (models.Model):
        comp_name= models.CharField(max_length=20)
        comp_actv_status=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        created_dt=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.comp_name
class deploy_dtl (models.Model):
        env=models.ForeignKey('env_master', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
        comp=models.ForeignKey('comp_master', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
        deploy_version=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        deploy_status=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        deploy_reqster_nme=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        created_dt=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        created_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        remarks=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.deploy_version```
````

Comment: Is this a solution to your problem or additional information?

Comment: You should have edited the question and placed this code there.